# Error Message 156 C# Saving Failure

Tags: c#, datagridview, sqlcommand

i am using this code for a while now and suddenly it stopped working and give the error near the keywork 'Transaction' which is my Data Table name 
i just can't find any problem could you please help me? thank you very much

here's my code

```
 try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow items in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Open();

                string buy_unitname = items.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                string buy_quantity = items.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                string buy_srp = items.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                string buy_transNo = items.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                string buy_date = items.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                string buy_total_srp = items.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                string buy_cart_no = items.Cells[6].Value.ToString();

                string str_conn2 ="insert into Transaction(UnitName,Quantity,SRP,TransactionNumber,Date,Total_SRP,Cart_no) values (@unitname_1,@quantity_1,@srp_1,@trans_1,@date_1,@total_srp_1,@cart_no_1)";
                SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(str_conn2, conn);
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unitname_1", buy_unitname);
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity_1", buy_quantity);
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@srp_1", buy_srp);
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trans_1", buy_transNo);
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_1", buy_date);
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total_srp_1", buy_total_srp);
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cart_no_1", buy_cart_no);
                sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one thing that I can see as a problem here.  The fact that you are opening and closing the SQL connection for every row in the dataGridView may cause some timing issues.

May be try this:

```
conn.Close();
conn.Open();

foreach (DataGridViewRow items in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    string buy_unitname = items.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    string buy_quantity = items.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    string buy_srp = items.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    string buy_transNo = items.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    string buy_date = items.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    string buy_total_srp = items.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
    string buy_cart_no = items.Cells[6].Value.ToString();

    string str_conn2 ="insert into Transaction(UnitName,Quantity,SRP,TransactionNumber,Date,Total_SRP,Cart_no) values (@unitname_1,@quantity_1,@srp_1,@trans_1,@date_1,@total_srp_1,@cart_no_1)";
    SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(str_conn2, conn);
    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unitname_1", buy_unitname);
    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity_1", buy_quantity);
    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@srp_1", buy_srp);
    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trans_1", buy_transNo);
    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_1", buy_date);
    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total_srp_1", buy_total_srp);
    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cart_no_1", buy_cart_no);
    sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();  
}

conn.Close();
```